# How to add duration between two times to listview in vb .NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a ListView that I want to get the duration between the two times and add in the fifth column for each row.

> I have no any idea how i can do this.
> If you can help me, so show me with code please.
> Like this:

[image]

I tried with this code, but it's not work:

```
For Each it As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            Dim dFrom As DateTime
            Dim dTo As DateTime
            Dim sDateFrom As String = it.SubItems(1).Text
            Dim sDateTo As String = it.SubItems(2).Text
            If DateTime.TryParse(sDateFrom, dFrom) AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(sDateTo, dTo) Then
                Dim TS As TimeSpan = dTo - dFrom
                Dim hour As Integer = TS.Hours
                Dim mins As Integer = TS.Minutes
                Dim secs As Integer = TS.Seconds
                Dim msec As Integer = TS.Milliseconds
                Dim timeDiff As String = ((hour.ToString("00") & ":") + mins.ToString("00") & ":") + secs.ToString("00") + "." + msec.ToString("000")            
                it.SubItems.Add(timeDiff)
            End If
```

Comment: `Next` usaually helps a For Each loop. :-)

Comment: Is that a comma in the list view separating the seconds from the milliseconds for the Start and End times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same loop where you populate the control to calculate and add the duration subitem. You don't need to do that in a separate loop. Convert the `StartDate` & `EndDate` strings to `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` objects, subtract the end time from the start time to get a `TimeSpan` object with the duration, call the `ToString` method and pass the `"s\.fff"` format to set the value of the duration's subitem.

**Example**

```vb
Imports System.Globalization
```

```vb
Dim inFormat = "hh\:mm\:ss\,fff"
Dim outFormat = "s\.fff"
Dim provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

For Each lvi As ListViewItem In listView1.Items
    Dim tsStart As TimeSpan, tsEnd As TimeSpan

    If TimeSpan.TryParseExact(lvi.SubItems(1).Text, inFormat, provider, tsStart) AndAlso
        TimeSpan.TryParseExact(lvi.SubItems(2).Text, inFormat, provider, tsEnd) Then
        lvi.SubItems.Add((tsEnd - tsStart).ToString(outFormat))
    End If
Next
```

In case and in somehow you already have the duration subitem in the collection, set it's `.Text` property instead of calling the `.Add(...)` method.

```vb
lvi.SubItems(4).Text = (tsEnd - tsStart).ToString(outFormat)
```

Again, you don't need a separate loop, in the main loop where you add the other subitems, replace the `lvi.SubItems(1).Text` and `lvi.SubItems(2).Text` parameters in the preceding example with their sources. Their properties in a *model* or their variables if you don't have a model.

Comment: WOW! This is perfect. this is exactly what I was looking for. Dear dr.null, as always the answer is short and correct this code works like a charm, and you are the best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code

I think you can do it by using the source below.

```
      Dim dFrom As DateTime
      Dim dTo As DateTime
      Dim sDateFrom As String = "00:00:06.200"
      Dim sDateTo As String = "00:00:07.680"

      If DateTime.TryParse(sDateFrom, dFrom) AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(sDateTo, dTo) Then

         Dim TS As TimeSpan = dTo - dFrom
         Dim hour As Integer = TS.Hours
         Dim mins As Integer = TS.Minutes
         Dim secs As Integer = TS.Seconds
         Dim msec As Integer = TS.Milliseconds

         Dim timeDiff As String = ((hour.ToString("00") & ":") + mins.ToString("00") & ":") + secs.ToString("00") + "." + msec.ToString("000")
         MsgBox(timeDiff) 'output 
      End If
```

Comment: The answer was great, and it works like a charm, but to add it to the list view unfortunately does not work. As I showed in the cod above.

Comment: @vahidAraghi Did you try swapping the line `MsgBox(timeDiff)` to what you show in your question, `it.SubItems.Add(timeDiff)`?

Comment: @SeanSkelly Yes, I did, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have a column ready to receive the new `SubItem`.
I proceeded with the comma that I asked about in comments. You can changed the `.ParseExact` if it is really a period.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With ListView1.Columns
        .Add("Start Time")
        .Add("End Time")
        .Add("Duration")
    End With
    Dim li As New ListViewItem("00:00:06,200")
    li.SubItems.Add("00:00:07,680")
    ListView1.Items.Add(li)
End Sub
```

Even though the first column is the `ListViewItem` is the Text property, it is also `SubItems(0)`. This can be confusing. You do have your indexes correct.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    For Each li As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
        Dim sDateFrom As String = li.SubItems(0).Text 'also works with il.Text
        Dim sDateTo As String = li.SubItems(1).Text
        Dim FormatString = "hh:mm:ss,fff"
        Dim provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        Dim StartTime = Date.ParseExact(sDateFrom, FormatString, provider)
        Dim EndTime = Date.ParseExact(sDateTo, FormatString, provider)
        Dim TS As TimeSpan = EndTime - StartTime
        'Dim timeDiff As String = $"{TS.Hours:00}:{TS.Minutes:00}:{TS.Seconds:00}.{TS.Milliseconds:000}"
        'or
        Dim timeDiff = TS.ToString("c")
        li.SubItems.Add(timeDiff)
    Next
End Sub
```

When you have a string with several variables that need to be inserted use an interpolated string which is preceded by a `$`. This allows you to insert your variables directly in line enclosed in `{ }`. This is much easier to write, read, and understand. You also avoid many mistakes with quotes and concatenation characters. Formatting of the variables is accomplished by the format following a colon inside the braces. If you can stand a few extra zeros, you can format the TimeSpan directly with `.ToString("c")`.